# Why am I getting an Improper dimensions error in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to create a simple ANN model in keras. However, I am getting the following error.

`Error when checking target: expected dense_8 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (36069, 1)`

Here is my model and input data.

```
x = x.reshape(48074,1,18,1)
x_train = x[0:36069]
x_val = x[36069:38472]
x_test = x[38472:48074]
y_train = y[0:36069]#36069
y_val = y[36069:38472]
y_test = y[38472:48074]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50),input_shape=(1,18,1))
model.add(Dense(25))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=10, verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

I tried `model.summary()` but could not find my error.

```
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 1, 18, 50)         100       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 1, 18, 25)         1275      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 1, 18, 1)          26
```

Comment: This is not all your code, where is the input_shape to the first layer of the model?

Comment: I have made the necessary changes

Comment: By all code I mean the full model definition (model variable is not defined), and there is no fit call.

Comment: Could u kindly check my code now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should flatten your data, because by default a Dense layer will only operate on the last dimension of the data.

```
x = x.reshape(48074,1 * 18 * 1)
x_train = x[0:36069]
x_val = x[36069:38472]
x_test = x[38472:48074]
y_train = y[0:36069]#36069
y_val = y[36069:38472]
y_test = y[38472:48074]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50),input_shape=(1 * 18 * 1,))
model.add(Dense(25))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=10, verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```